# Can my supervisor force me to publish my master’s thesis?

Tags: publications, thesis, advisor, authorship

I defended my master’s thesis in engineering. My advisor didn't help me much.
Now he wants to publish the thesis as a scientific article. Even if he will write the article, I don't want the project to be published for several reasons:

I didn't like the topic that much and I don't have time, energy and interest anymore. The method has some serious issues and needs more work. I don't feel comfortable with publishing the thesis as it is now because I think it's really bad honestly, but at the same time I really don't want to spend energy explaining what to further work on, cleaning the code etc.

This thesis was really psychologically stressful for me, I felt desperate and alone; and I would like to just say no and close this chapter forever. I don't know if I am obliged to send the codes and data or if I can refuse doing so.
Does someone have any suggestion on how I should proceed?

I am 100% sure I will not work in academia, so I don't even care about publishing in view of a possible PhD.

Answer (score 5):

Publication ethics require the permission of all authors to publish.  So no, your supervisor cannot force you.  This ethical requirement applies even if your supervisor holds the copyright for some reason.

That said, there is probably no downside for you to allow your supervisor to use their time to publish the paper.  If your work is not medical and not on a controversial social issue, it's likely any real or perceived methodological issues will not impact your non-academic career.  If the supervisor wastes their time on a rejected submission, that won't impact you.

Refusing permission will hurt your reputation.

> I don't know if I am obliged to send the codes and data

Providing them would be a more ethical choice.

Comment: *Publication ethics require the permission of all authors to publish.* – You should add that it also requires the asker to be an author. (I presume you took this for granted, but the asker may not.)

Comment: Good answer. The complete answer to _I don't know if I am obliged to send the codes and data_ requires knowing the funding source and university policies/local laws. But, you are correct, providing is the ethical choice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where you are located. In Germany, you are the author of your thesis, so you hold the copyright and can decide what you want to do with the written expression of your research. If you were paid for by the university, you *may* have signed away a right to use the results research, so you will have to check anything you have signed. This is a complex problem, it is usually better to get this sorted out before you begin working, but it crops up usually when the research is over.

If the professor publishes without your permission, you then may want to publish a paper discussing this issues you have identified :)